# Error trying to join Azure storage account to domain

Tags: active-directory, powershell, azure

I'm running into an error running Powershell (v5.1) cmdlet Join-AzStorageAccount to join an Azure storage account to my domain. I just did this successfully with a storage account, but when I try to do a second one, I get the error below. I will say when I started it the second time, it hung and I had to kill the PS session and start over. However, the second storage does NOT exist on the DC, but I still keep getting this error. I feel like there is meta data hiding somewhere but I don't know where to go to find it or clean it up.

Power Shell error:

New-ADComputer : The specified account already exists

At C:\Users\{user}\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzFilesHybrid\0.2.8.0\AzFilesHybrid.psm1:2779 char:21

- New-ADComputer `
- 
- CategoryInfo : ResourceExists: (CN=xxbackup,OU...C=xxxxxx,DC=com:String) [New-ADComputer], ADIdentityAlreadyExistsException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:1316,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADComputer

Snippet of my script:

Join-AzStorageAccount `

-ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `

-StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName `

-SamAccountName $SamAccountName `

-DomainAccountType $DomainAccountType `

-OrganizationalUnitDistinguishedName $OuDistinguishedName `

-EncryptionType $EncryptionType

The variables all contain valid values just like when I did it the first time, the only difference being the name of the storage account and the OuDistinguishedName. Anybody run into this issue or see what I'm doing wrong?  Again, I just did it and it worked, but for a second storage account it did not.

Thanks,

Phil

Answer (score 0):

`) [New-ADComputer], ADIdentityAlreadyExistsException`

This error suggests that there is already a computer account. I would try to search the ad to see if I can find that computer account and delete when found, and then try again.

You could also try to search with PowerShell `Get-ADComputer`.

Comment: Hi, like I said, the account does not exist.  I also used that PowerShell command.  However, two days later, I tried it again, and it worked,  So I'll chalk it up to Microsoft flakiness.